# No .aspx page suffix, how come?

Tags: asp.net, iis

How come stackoverflow hasn't any .aspx page suffix in the url bar? Everything ends up in /something/ or /page

How can I achieve the same in asp.net?

Comment: Those are called 'friendly urls'. How you achieve them depends on what framework approach on top of ASP.NET are you using.

Comment: Thanks, what info should I provide? I'm using IIS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of webforms (and aspx pages) you could use MVC and it's routing feature (see http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/controllers-and-routing) where a url is mapped to an "action" in a "controller".

A URL of `/questions/25364620/whatever` could be mapped to the "Index" action (a default value) of the "QuestionsController" ("questions" from the URL + "Controller"), with an id parameter of 25364620. The title is ignored.

Answer (score 0):

These are called the [friendly urls](http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/friendly-urls). I am not sure about how they have written in Stackoverflow but you can remove the .aspx entension by doing like this:

```
<rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="RewriteMyASPX">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}.aspx" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```